# mouse pointer position using javascript is not working for internet explorer

Tags: javascript

I am getting problem when trying to get mouse pointer position using javascript. My code is working in ie10 to ie7 in document Quirk mode. but when i change the ie browser version then by default it change it in quirk ie5 document mode. In standard mode my javascript is not working.Please help me. This is my code. I want set my div width dynamically with mouse pointer.

```
var IE = document.all?true:false




// If NS -- that is, !IE -- then set up for mouse capture
if (!IE) document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE)

// Set-up to use getMouseXY function onMouseMove
document.onmousemove = getMouseXY;

// Temporary variables to hold mouse x-y pos.s
var tempX = 0
var tempY = 0

// Main function to retrieve mouse x-y pos.s

function getMouseXY(e) {
  if (IE) { // grab the x-y pos.s if browser is IE
    tempX = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
    tempY = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;

    //alert("tempx"+tempX); 
    //alert("tempY"+tempY);
  } else {  // grab the x-y pos.s if browser is NS
    tempX = e.pageX;
    tempY = e.pageY;

    //alert("tempx"+tempX); 

  }

  if(tempX <= 850){ 
   document.getElementById('content').style.width = tempX;
  }
  return true
```

Comment: I would not target anything below IE8. Do you need to?

Comment: For reference you can simply `!!document.all` instead of `document.all ? true : false`.

Comment: I have tried !!document.all but it does not change my content div width dynamically. I am testing it with alert but it is not going in  if condition.

Comment: Hi i have solved this. I have changed document.getElementById('divisor').style.width = tempX this to jQuery("#divisor").css('width', tempX); and now it is working fine.